# iOS: Why is the background black?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I am creating an an application for iPhone (based on the template for "utility application").
Using interface builder, I have created a settings view as shown below. The gray background is an UIView with gray background color. But when I run the app, the background becomes black!

Can someone explain why?

[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, look at your FlipsideViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];      
}
```

The second line does the trick.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Irene, I removed the line and now its works as intended!